# Is it possible to limit the configuration rollback count in MX-series?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I tried `set system max-configuration-rollbacks` in mx480, but it shows `unsupported platform` .

```
##
## Warning: statement ignored: unsupported platform (mx480)
##
max-configuration-rollbacks 25;
```

is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.  This feature was targeted at smaller form-factor platforms (e.g. SRX) that don't have full blown hard drives like the MX (hence why you see it say unsupported).  SRX also has another statement to specify the number of rollbacks stored on the flash as well.

I work with some devices that have massive configurations (~450000 lines / 16M), this is **NOT** common, though even with the default of 50 rollbacks that's only ~750M out of multiple G available to the root partition on an MX480.